# How to finish an activity with presentation hint?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross in my Xamarin.Android application. I want to be able to finish the current activity with a presentation hint. Here is my view presenter:

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    public ViewPresenter(IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Assembly> assemblies) : base(assemblies)
    {
        AddPresentationHintHandler<PopViewModelHint>(OnPopViewModelHint);
    }

    private bool OnPopViewModelHint(PopViewModelHint popViewModel)
    {
        // how to finish current activity?
        return true;
    }
}
```

From my view model:

```
ChangePresentation(new PopViewModelHint());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MvxAndroidViewPresenter` exposes the current active `Activity` via the `CurrentActivity` property.

```
private bool OnPopViewModelHint(PopViewModelHint popViewModel)
{
    CurrentActivity?.Finish();
    return true;
}
```